# Html 5 Canvas keeping track of position when rotating rendered image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to get this working but nothing yet! My math level isn't that good as well. What I have right now is that I have an arrow which is pointing North and when the mouse is being held, the arrow points to where the mouse moves. I have a bounding box that determines when the arrow is being selected with the mouse.

After a rotation however, I lose that bounding box as it is still on the original position. Is there anyway to make the bounding box move to the new coordinates or is there any way where when I click on the rotated arrow, I make the arrow know that it is being clicked on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post a simplified version of your problem in code?

Comment: See this [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5494/transformations/19666/a-transformation-matrix-to-track-translated-rotated-scaled-shapes) which shows how track your rotations and how to test if the mouse is inside the rotated rectangle (arrow).